# PostgreSQL - Error "42701" when try to create view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to create a view which contains calculated data from others table. However, I have this error message: `[42701] ERROR: column "id" specified more than once`.

My SQL script:

```
CREATE VIEW dashboard_view AS
   SELECT c.libelle_commune AS "commune",
       count(bv.id) AS "total_bv",
       count(rsb.id) AS "bv_saisis",
       count(bv.id) - count(rsb.id) AS "bv_en_attente",
       count(rsb.id) / count(bv.id) * 100 AS "pourcentage_saisie",
       count(rsb_t.id) AS "bv_transmis_sie2",
       count(rsb_t.id) / count(bv.id) * 100 AS "pourcentage_transmission",
       d.id,
       c.id
   FROM commune "c"
       JOIN departement "d" ON d.id = c.departement_id
       JOIN bureau_de_vote "bv" ON bv.commune_id = c.id
       LEFT JOIN scrutin_bureau "sb" ON sb.bureau_de_vote_id = bv.id
       LEFT JOIN resultat_scrutin_bureau "rsb" ON rsb.scrutin_bureau_id = sb.id
       LEFT JOIN resultat_scrutin_bureau "rsb_t" ON (
           rsb_t.scrutin_bureau_id = sb.id
           AND rsb_t.etat_id = (SELECT id FROM etat WHERE code = 'transmission')
       )
       JOIN election ON sb.election_id = election.id
   GROUP BY c.id, d.id;
```

Comment: be sue `(SELECT id FROM etat WHERE code = 'transmission')`  only return one row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSql unable to create view due to "duplicate column"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834806/postgresql-unable-to-create-view-due-to-duplicate-column)

Comment: This is not a problem in this context @jian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting

```
d.id, c.id
```

Both columns cannot be present in the view with the name `id` - you'll need to give at least one of them an alias, probably both with an alias name that describes what the `id` represents.

Answer (score 2):

As Error specified you try to create two columns with name `id` in your query.

very simplified example of incorrect view creation with same error:

```sql
CREATE VIEW a AS
SELECT 1 AS hello, 2 AS hello;
```

And correct one

```sql
CREATE VIEW a AS
SELECT 1 AS hello, 2 AS world;
```

So in order to fix your query change

```
CREATE VIEW dashboard_view AS
   SELECT c.libelle_commune AS "commune",
       count(bv.id) AS "total_bv",
       count(rsb.id) AS "bv_saisis",
       count(bv.id) - count(rsb.id) AS "bv_en_attente",
       count(rsb.id) / count(bv.id) * 100 AS "pourcentage_saisie",
       count(rsb_t.id) AS "bv_transmis_sie2",
       count(rsb_t.id) / count(bv.id) * 100 AS "pourcentage_transmission",
       d.id,
       c.id
```

into

```
CREATE VIEW dashboard_view AS
   SELECT c.libelle_commune AS "commune",
       count(bv.id) AS "total_bv",
       count(rsb.id) AS "bv_saisis",
       count(bv.id) - count(rsb.id) AS "bv_en_attente",
       count(rsb.id) / count(bv.id) * 100 AS "pourcentage_saisie",
       count(rsb_t.id) AS "bv_transmis_sie2",
       count(rsb_t.id) / count(bv.id) * 100 AS "pourcentage_transmission",
       d.id AS departement_id,
       c.id AS commune_id
```